# Creating Shortcut with batch and vbs

Tags: command-line, vbscript, batch-file, shortcut

I am trying to make a simple (or at least I thought) batch file to find files of a specific file type and then create shortcuts to open them using a specific program.

After a lot of digging I found this is best done with VBScript so I created a little script to make shortcuts for me. This isn't working so I was hoping someone could tell me why. Thank you.

MakeShortcuts.bat:

```
SET ShortcutPath=c:\shortcuts\
SET ProgramPath="c:\windows\notepad.exe"
SET SearchBaseDir="C:\Documents and Settings\"

FOR /R %SearchBaseDir% %%i IN (*.gba) DO (
createShortcut "%ShortcutPath%Open %%~ni.lnk" "%ProgramPath%" "%%i"
)
```

createShortcut.vbs:

```
set obShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sShortcut = obShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
sTargetPath = obShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
sArgument = obShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(2))
set shortcut = obShell.CreateShortcut(sShortcut) 
shortcut.TargetPath = sTargetPath
shortcut.Arguments = sArgument
shortcut.Save
```

Ok, so when I ran MakeShortcuts.bat it give me the message [The system cannot find the drive specified.] in the command line.

It creates the shortcuts as expected except that the target has no quotes around the argument which is preventing the shortcuts from functioning properly. I think this also may be related to the above error message as well.

I am very new to VBScript so I am probably missing something pretty stupid. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the problem is in the VBScript, it is probably in the batch file.  The value that you assign to SearchBaseDir should be enclosed within double quotes, like this:

```
SET SearchBaseDir="C:\Documents and Settings\"
```

Then, you need to remove the quotes from the parameters that you pass to createShortcut.

You also need to decide whether you are going to be using %%i or %%f, because using both is inconsistent. Either rename %%i to %%f, or %%f to %%i.

Finally, I am not absolutely sure about this, but the last %%f might have to be replaced with %%~f so as to get rid of the double quotes, if by any chance its value contains double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the %%f and %%i issue, i rewrote the code to remove specifics of the program but copied and pasted bits from the original. I edited my example above but didn't have the same mistake in the original. What do you mean use [%%~i] what would that do? I made the other changes you suggested but still have the same results. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: %%~i will remove the double quotes from the value of %%i if the value is already surrounded by double quotes. Anyway, my advice would be to first replace the createShortcut command with an echo command and make sure that your batch file works perfectly before you move on to looking for problems in your VBScript.